# out of memory by resizing bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, inputstream

I am trying to resize a bitmap to custom X and Y and the code I am using runs sometimes into *OutOfMemory* exception. I looked here around and found some solutions how to use *InputStream* to resize bitmaps, but I was not able to find any approach how to resize it to custom X and Y dimensions . Could somebody give me an advice?

here is my code:

```
try {

            Point scr = Sys.screenSize(getActivity());

                    // MY CUSTOM X and Y    
            int newWidth = (int) Sys.convertDpToPixel(linheight, getActivity())
                    * lines;
            int newHeight = scr.x;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity()
                    .getResources(), R.drawable.field);

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

            // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
            bm = Bitmap
                    .createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
            bitmap.recycle();
            matrix = null;
            iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is createScaledBitmap:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = 
       Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```